# Making eclipse faster after adding properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

Sorry, if this issue is simple. I tried a lot to find a solution, but was not able to find one.
My issue:

```
Project
|
|-Java Resources
      |-src/main/resources
          |-xyz.properties
```

Above is my project structure. I am adding more and more properties file in src/main/resources source folder. But after adding each properties file, my eclipse is getting slower and slower. After having 20 files, its getting stuck for a long period of time. 
What I tried is that, edited eclipse.ini file, as shown below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1G
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1G
-Xmx2G
```

But not much improvement after increasing MaxPermsize too.

Example for my properties file:

```
PC_WELL_384=384-Well
PC_STANDRD_PLATE=Standard Plate
PC_SMALL_SCALE_PLATE=Small Scale Plate
PC_INVALID_TOTAL_ORDER_UNITS_5 =Total ordering units is less than 5
PC_INVALID_TOTAL_ORDER_UNITS_10 =Total ordering units is less than 10
```

Like these 10000 lines of key value pair in each file

These properties are used in java file and also in jsf UI component. I have various properties file based on locale. Based on the locale, jsf pages will get the value of particular key from particular property file. And in java file I am getting it using resource bundle. Eg: bundle.getString("_PC_ERROR_OLIGO_INVALID_SEQUENCE_PCR");

Example code where I am using these properties file is:

```
private ResourceBundle bundle;
bundle = XyzUtil.getResourceBundle(locale);//Getting bundle based on locale

this.errorMessages = bundle.getString("_PC_ERROR_OLIGO_INVALID_SEQUENCE_PCR");//getting value of specified key from my properties file.
```

Implementation of getResourceBundle(locale) method is:

```
public static ResourceBundle getResourceBundle(Locale locale) {
        return ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME, locale,
                ResourceBundle.Control.getNoFallbackControl(ResourceBundle.Control.FORMAT_PROPERTIES));
    }
```

I am using this value from properties file for setting some values in my application.

I am struggling. Can someone help me to make my eclipse faster and responsive.

Comment: Please provide an example properties file.

Comment: I have added the example

Comment: What do you mean by " my eclipse is getting slower and slower. "? If it slow while you write code? Or is it slow when your program compiles and runs?

Comment: It is slow while saving and compiling, while opening the file. It is also getting slow while opening other files too.

Comment: I think that the problem is due to the sheer size of your files. 10,000 lines seems like too much for eclipse to handle.

Comment: Actually I can't reduce the size also.I need these data. Is there any way out?

Comment: Why do these files need to be in the eclipse project? Are they used to help compile your software? Or are they used when your program runs? Can you save them somewhere else and open them from there?

Comment: these properties are used in java file and also in jsf UI component.  I have various properties file based on locale. Based on the locale, jsf pages will get the value of particular key from particular property file. And in java file I am getting it using resource bundle. Eg: bundle.getString("_PC_ERROR_OLIGO_INVALID_SEQUENCE_PCR");

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the code which is reading these properties files?  You should not need to read a properties file more than once per request.

Comment: @VGR done. Let me know if it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the fact that the [m2e plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), which implements the Maven/Eclipse integration, executes the [`resources:resources` goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) whenever Eclipse builds something incrementally, e.g., whenever you save a `.java` file.

To verify this, open the “Console” view and switch to the “Maven Console”. On a build, you should see output like the following:

```
9/13/16, 9:53:19 AM GMT+2: [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
9/13/16, 9:53:19 AM GMT+2: [INFO] Copying 1 resource
```

With your huge resource files, copying resources all the time is obviously not a good idea. I don’t know a good workaround, however, but the [m2e-users mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/m2e-users) seems like the perfect place to ask about this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My project is a gradle project.